# How to style, or contain in a div, content loading with jqueries .load()? Another quicky

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The content I'm loading with jquery .load() takes up too much of the screen when it loads into a small div?

Anyone know what's going on here? Any way to style content while it's in transition?

```
$('.selector').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000,function() {$('.display').load('..content/content.php')});

$('.selector').show("slide",{direction:"left"},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in many different visual style, I will give two examples:

1. Sytle the `$('.display')` to be hidden by default, then on the `success callback` of `load()` (third parameter), style it to become visible
2. Give `.diplay` a style of fixed height, while the container (the `.selector`) has the style of `overflow: hidden`, then when the animation is finished, turn it back to `overflow: none`

generally, your problem is with animation. Also, I recommend using the function `$.ajax()` which gives you more control over the flow of loading. It has many more `callback`s.